# Excel finding duplicate data and pasting it in new sheet

Tags: excel

Curious if there's a way to find duplicate data from 2 columns in 2 sheets and then pasting the entire row of one sheet. For instance, I have extracted data from 2 different sources and I want to see if any of the data in rows a and b in sheets 1 and 2 match. If so, I want to have the data row from sheet 1 pasted into a summary sheet.

Comment: You could use `=Countifs(Sheet2!A:A, A1, Sheet2!B:B, B1)` in Sheet1 and copy down, then sort it by the results and copy paste to your new sheet.

Comment: You could use Power Query to merge both sources with an inner join, and output the result to a separate sheet.